# CentOS loses internet connection

Tags: centos, networking, virtualbox, configuration, internet

I have configured CentOS VM, with NetworkManager disabled.

### Question:

When I start VM I have access to the internet, but after a while I lose it.
How can I fix that?

Comment: If additional info is needed, please, feel free to tell me, I'll do my best to get it and add to topic.

Comment: Hey Denis, can you try to run `traceroute` to see where it's failing !

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in step one, you say:

> When I start VM I have access to the internet, but after a while I lose it:

test this on console:

```
dhclient -v
```

You will notice it will bound IP address as shown below

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.5 Copyright 2004-2013
Internet Systems Consortium. All rights reserved. For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/ Listening on LPF/ens32/00:0c:29:68:22:e2
Sending on   LPF/ens32/00:0c:29:68:22:e2
Sending on   Socket/fallback DHCPDISCOVER on ens32 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x433a9e33) DHCPREQUEST on ens32 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x433a9e33)
DHCPOFFER from 172.16.179.254 DHCPACK from 172.16.179.254 (xid=0x433a9e33) bound to 172.16.179.136 -- renewal in 822 seconds.
```

then run this command to show your IP:

```
ip addr or ifconfig
```

then you should add to startup for auto/start :
go to : 
cd /etc/init.d

create net-autostart file with sudo vim and save it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Solution for "Centos Connection from VMware"
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
### END INIT INFO
dhclient -v
```

run command :

```
chmode +755 net-autostart

chconfig --add net-autostart
```

restart virtualbox

Comment: The OP isn't using VMware. Well, according to the tags they're using [tag:VirtualBox].

Comment: @roaima I don't think it is really matters in this case

Comment: @farhad azim thanks, it seems to be working, but I'll wait a while to be sure.

Comment: @DenisSablukov I couldn't work out what this solution is trying to fix, so I couldn't assume the VM environment was irrelevant.